# Site Assets - MP4 file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, site, video

I loaded a **MP4 file** (around 5MB) to a site **assets library**.
When I try to edit the properties I get this error:

> The URL  is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue.

> To work around this issue, remove the Version column from the list of
>   Indexed Columns for the list that has this issue. To do this, follow
>   these steps: Browse to the list where the issue exists. In the ribbon,
>   click the Library tab, and then click Library Settings. In the fields
>   list, click Indexed Columns. In the Indexed Columns list, click
>   Version. Click Delete, and then click OK. Upload any files that you
>   previously experienced the issue with.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2796640

Comment: I do not have indexed columns